# Python SqlAlchemy - sqlalchemy-sqlany dialect connection string

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sybase, sqlanywhere

I could not find anything on the topic so decided to start somewhere..

```
url="sqlalchemy_sqlany://admin:123456@localhost/"
eng=create_engine(url,connect_args={'dbf': "/home/user/Desktop/dummy_db.db", 
'ServerName':'plc_pi'})
```

If someone knows a neat way to create the connection from file it would be great to share.

Credits to : Goutham as well

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to read the connection parameters from a configuration file...?

Comment: Yes, I would prefer to "hold" the connection paramers in a config file. I can store my info in a file, I am asking if there is a format that can be directly binded to the create_engine() method. Also sharing info, about the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand the question correctly. The engine can be created using a connection string. The format of this connection string depends on the DBMS you are using. For an overview of the different connection strings and sqlalchemy see: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html

The create_engine is called with a connection string. This connection string can be read from numerous of different file formats. See https://martin-thoma.com/configuration-files-in-python/ for a first overview of different types of configuration files. One to point out is to use a python configuration file for its ease of use, the possibilities it provides (because it is python you can easily build strings in the configuration and so on).

As an example here is how you could do it using a JSON file:

```
import json

with open('config.json') as config_file:
    data = json.load(config_file)
print(data['database']['connection_string'])

engine = create_engine(data['database']['connection_string'])
```

Hope this solves your question. If not please leave a comment…

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I am aware I can handle it on my own. (as in your example create a json file, though I would prefer binary+encr). I was hoping that sqlalchemy can handle this file creation with 1 liner.